# Не работает If elif else

Tags: python

```
from random import randint

random_num = randint(1, 10)
print(random_num)
attempt = 0
user_num = 0
while True:
    print("Угадай число")
    user_num = str(input("Введите число(от 1 до 10): "))
    attempt += 1
    if user_num == random_num:
        print("Ты угадал\nКоличество твоих поп : " + str(attempt))
        break
    elif user_num > random_num:
        print("Моё число меньше")
    elif user_num < random_num:
        print("Моё число больше")
```

В терминале:

> C:\Users\atv\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:\Users\atv\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\RRR.py
> 2
> Угадай число
> Введите число(от 1 до 10): 2
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\atv\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\RRR.py", line 14, in 
> elif user_num > random_num:
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
> Process finished with exit code 1**

Comment: У тебя user_num строка приведи его к числу и все будет ок

Answer (score 1):

Преобразуйте пользовательский ввод число, если хотите работать с ним как с числом.
`user_num = int(input("Введите число(от 1 до 10): "))`

Comment: Спасибо, это сработало